# Images center on localhost but not on live server

Tags: html, css

The code works on my local machine but when I have it live on a server it doesn't work. I'm just trying to center images within a div

```
  <div class="front-end">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading title"><h4 style="text-align:left;">Front End</h4></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
     <img id="mImg" src="./pictures/HTML5_Badge.png" alt="" style="width:90px;height:92px;">
     <img id="mImg" src="./pictures/css_badge.jpg" alt="" style="width:98px;height:100px;">
     <img id="mImg" src="./pictures/bootstrap_badge.png" alt="" 
              style="width:90px;height:92px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're not loading any CSS or HTML from the server cache. Recycle any app pools you're using and be sure to force your browser to load a fresh copy of any code by pressing CTRL + F5.

Answer (score 1):

You should steer clear of using inline styling, instead put all your styling in a stylesheet, it will make your code easier to manage. Additionally, all 3 of your images contain the same `ID`, but [IDs must be unique](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp). You are also missing a closing `</div>` which is probably what's causing your issue.

```css
.panel-heading h4 {
  text-align:left;
}
.panel-body .row {
  text-align:center;
}
img#html5-badge {
  width:90px;
  height:92px;
}
img#css-badge {
  width:98px;
  height:100px;
}
img#bootstrap-badge {
  width:90px;
  height:92px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-end">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading title">
      <h4>Front End</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <img id="html5-badge" src="http://placehold.it/180x184" alt="" />
        <img id="css-badge" src="http://placehold.it/196x200" alt="" />
        <img id="bootstrap-badge" src="http://placehold.it/180x184" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```